# How can I make the the versus mode fights more challenging in Ultimate Ninja Storm Revolution?

Tags: naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-rev

I'm just starting the B campaign, and I notice that the network clones I'm fighting against are ridiculously good. After getting trashed by quite a few of them, I decided to practice using the "versus mode" in "free battle mode". However, I'm able to easily defeat the bots there.

I don't see any difficulty slider, is there any way to make the bots more challenging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I finally found out how to do it.

You need to hit `Start` to bring up the battle settings page which allows difficulty customization.